# How to properly use onNext with .map with links, so far only the final link works

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to list our these 4 Shirt images and link to that shirt's homepage when the image is clicked on. Only the final link works (onNext("ANECKHOME")). Is there a better solution that I may be overlooking?  Below is my data set and the code.

**Data Set is shirtTypesData**

```
export const shirtTypes = [
  {
    name: "SHORTSLEEVE",
    image: "https://imagelink1.png",
  },
  {
    name: "LONGSLEEVE",
    image: "https://imagelink2.png",
  },
  {
    name: "VNECK",
    image: "https://imagelink3.png",
  },
  {
    name: "ANECK",
    image: "https://imagelink4.png",
  },
];
```

**component is SelectShirtType**

```
import React from "react";
import { shirtTypes } from "./shirtTypesData";


const SelectShirtType = ({ onNext}) => (
  <main>
    <h3>Available Tshirts for Purchase</h3>
    <hr />
    <div className="boxes">
      {shirtTypes.map((type) => (
        <button
          style={type.name !== "SHORTSLEEVE" ?  : null}
          className="product-outer-box"
          onClick={
            type.name == "SHORTSLEEVE"
              ? () => {
                  onNext("SHORTSLEEVEHOME");
                }
              : null
          }
          style={type.name !== "LONGSLEEVE" ?  : null}
          className="product-outer-box"
          onClick={
            type.name == "LONGSLEEVE"
              ? () => {
                  onNext("LONGSLEEVEHOME");
                }
              : null
          }
          style={type.name !== "VNECK" ?  : null}
          className="product-outer-box"
          onClick={
            type.name === "VNECK"
              ? () => {
                  onNext("VNECKHOME");
                }
              : null
          }
          style={type.name !== "ANECK" ?  : null}
          className="product-outer-box"
          onClick={
            type.name === "ANECK"
              ? () => {
                  onNext("ANECKHOME");
                }
              : null
          }
           >
          <div className="product-inner-box">
            <div className="image-box">
              <img src={type.image} alt={type.name} />
            </div>
            <div className="black-box">
              <p>{type.name}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  </main>
);

export default SelectShirtType;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the onClick property each time you write it out, that's why it only works in the last scenario.

Let's go by steps (solution at the bottom).

ClassName is always the same for all types, so instead of repeating that attribute, we'll just leave it once at the top of our `button` element:

```
<button
  className="product-outer-box"
  style={type.name !== "SHORTSLEEVE" ?  : null}
  style={type.name !== "LONGSLEEVE" ?  : null}
  style={type.name !== "VNECK" ?  : null}
  style={type.name !== "ANECK" ?  : null}
  onClick={
    type.name == "SHORTSLEEVE"
      ? () => {
          onNext("SHORTSLEEVEHOME");
        }
      : null
  }
  onClick={
    type.name == "LONGSLEEVE"
      ? () => {
          onNext("LONGSLEEVEHOME");
        }
      : null
  }
  onClick={
    type.name === "VNECK"
      ? () => {
          onNext("VNECKHOME");
        }
      : null
  }
  onClick={
    type.name === "ANECK"
      ? () => {
          onNext("ANECKHOME");
        }
      : null
  }
  >
  <div className="product-inner-box">
    <div className="image-box">
      <img src={type.image} alt={type.name} />
    </div>
    <div className="black-box">
      <p>{type.name}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>
```

Now we have a button that will always have a `style` attribute that is either "ANECK" or `null`, and an `onClick` attribute that will always contain the following:

```
type.name === "ANECK"
  ? () => {
    onNext("ANECKHOME");
  }
  : null
```

We should unify our `style` and `onClick` attributes into just one of each, like so:

```
<button
  className="product-outer-box"
  style={type.name}
  onClick={() => onNext(`${type.name}HOME`)}
  >
  <div className="product-inner-box">
    <div className="image-box">
      <img src={type.image} alt={type.name} />
    </div>
    <div className="black-box">
      <p>{type.name}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>
```

This way, our buttons will always have whatever `type.name` holds as their `style`, and when clicked will redirect our users to "`type.name` + HOME" (for example, if `type.name` is "SHORTSLEEVE", our onNext will take us to "SHORTSLEEVEHOME").

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```js
const SelectShirtType = ({ onNext}) => ( shirtTypes.map( type => (<button onClick={() => onNext(type.name.toUpperCase()+"HOME")}></button> ))
```